# How can I generate mesh distance fields at runtime on a procedural mesh in unreal engine 4.26?

Tags: procedural-generation, unreal-4, signed-distance-field

I am building a simulation game that and I that allows the player to create procedural buildings rather than placing static scenery items. If possible, I would like to write a shader that can take the vertices, normals, tangents, etc. and generate an identical mesh distance field so that I can leverage UE4's distance field ambient occlusion and so that various materials can detect generated geometry.

One project that appears to successfully achieve this is the Voxel Plugin. I have looked at the source but I am stumped as to where to start. I failed to find solid resources about this topic online. However, I did find this resource [techniques to generate distance fields](https://shaderbits.com/blog/various-distance-field-generation-techniques) but this is not clear enough. I Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: A voxel plugin is likely generating its distance field from the voxel representation (relatively easy/cheap), not from a mesh (difficult/expensive). You can leverage something similar: the operations you use to build up your procedural buildings might have associated structural information you can use to compute a distance field faster than treating the end result as a raw mesh/polygon soup. Try editing your question to walk us through the tools the player uses to create buildings, and we might be able to help you find those opportunities.

Comment: @DMGregory can you expand on that? I want to generate mesh distance fields for my meshes that I am generating at runtime. I'm generating those meshes from voxel data so I think it should be possible and not too expensive to do at runtime. My question is how exactly can it be done? Should I create a separate question? This one was obviously abandoned by JronFrt.

Comment: First, you should [follow the guide here to merge your accounts](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). Then you'll be able to edit your question above to add details about *how* you are generating those meshes from voxel data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But that is not my account :)
I just happen to have the same question.